# Не работают команды pycord

Tags: python, discord, бот, pycord

Решил перейти с старой библиотеки discord py на pycord, а в итоге ничего не работает. Этот код я взял с офицального сайта, хотел проверить будут ли работать команды
Вроде сделал все правильно

Первый код с pycord:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?") 

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")
    
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):    
    await ctx.send("pong")
    

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))

#Второй код бат c токеном:

@echo off 

call %~dp0bot\venv\Scripts\activate

cd %~dp0bot\main

set TOKEN=???

python main.py

pause
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоль выводятся?

Answer (score 0):

В pycord Новейшей версии в commands.Bot надо выставить аргумент intents

```
bot = commands.Bot(..., intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

Если не сработало, убедитесь что вы выдали боту на панели разработчика права MessageContentIntent